# about ip_hash in nginx upstream module

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I want to replace pound with nginx as loadbalancer and all tests look fine so far. I will do a typical upstream configuration like this:

```
upstream backend {
  ip_hash;
  server   backend1.example.com;
  server   backend2.example.com;
  server   backend3.example.com;
}
```

There are now 2 questions left open:

1. How long does this stickyness last? Is there a ttl to be defined somewhere?
2. Does the stickyness survive restarts and/or reloads of nginx?

I could not find the answer in the nginx wiki. Links to official docs are welcome.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is based on client source ip address hash and as long as you have same set of backends stickiness will persist.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#ip_hash

Answer (score 0):

It comes up when you do feel for need of session persistency. Scenario is like the users should be directed to same server as application demands based on previous connection.

*ip_hash = key-value pair hashing* [where key=**visitor's ip**, value=**host server**]